# Compile scss into separated paths with saving location

Tags: webpack, webpack-style-loader

I want to solve a simple task with Webpack. I just want to compile my .SCSS files into .CSS and save them with save paths and names.

For example:

1. I am in `/component/subcomponent` and I do `require('./first-style.scss')`
2. I am in `/module/component` and I again do `require('./second-style.scss')`

I want to compile scss -> css and after put them into
`/public/styles/component/subcomponent/first-style.css` and
`/public/styles/module/component/second-style.css`

And require should return string with new path `/public/styles/component/subcomponent/first-style.css`

I solved this task only for simple css (not scss), It looks like [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d199b72aea4bc6ff986d225674c20f00)

But I can't find the way to repeat it for SCSS. Who can help me?

Comment: If the rule for CSS already works, just add `sass-loader` to the loader string: `loader: 'file?name=styles/[2].[hash].[ext]&regExp=src/(.*)/app/(.*).css!autoprefixer-loader?browsers=last 2 versions!sass-loader'`. - And add .scss to your regex test: `test: /\.css$|\.scss$/,`